# Python pandas: how to find time difference based on maximum of other columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have been trying to find the time spent for most involved activity per person of this dataset:

```
              name  activity           timestamp  money_spent
0    Chandler Bing     party 2017-08-04 08:00:00           51
1    Chandler Bing     party 2017-08-04 13:00:00           60
2    Chandler Bing     party 2017-08-04 15:00:00           59
5       Harry Kane     party 2017-08-04 07:00:00           68
4       Harry Kane     party 2017-08-04 11:00:00           90
3       Harry Kane  football 2017-08-04 13:00:00           80
11  Joey Tribbiani  football 2017-08-04 08:00:00           84
9   Joey Tribbiani     party 2017-08-04 09:00:00           54
10  Joey Tribbiani     party 2017-08-04 10:00:00           67
6         John Doe     beach 2017-08-04 07:00:00           63
7         John Doe     beach 2017-08-04 12:00:00           61
8         John Doe     beach 2017-08-04 14:00:00           65
12   Monica Geller    travel 2017-08-04 07:00:00           90
13   Monica Geller    travel 2017-08-04 08:00:00           96
14   Monica Geller    travel 2017-08-04 09:00:00           74
15   Phoebe Buffey    travel 2017-08-04 10:00:00           52
16   Phoebe Buffey    travel 2017-08-04 12:00:00           84
17   Phoebe Buffey  football 2017-08-04 15:00:00           58
18     Ross Geller     party 2017-08-04 09:00:00           96
19     Ross Geller     party 2017-08-04 11:00:00           81
20     Ross Geller    travel 2017-08-04 14:00:00           60

df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

df # party day 2017-08-04 for some guys.
# find most involved activity and time spent on that activity per person.
```

Required output:

```
                activity_num activity time_diff
name                                           
Chandler Bing            1.0    party  07:00:00
Harry Kane               2.0    party  04:00:00
Joey Tribbiani           2.0    party  02:00:00
John Doe                 1.0    beach  07:00:00
Monica Geller            1.0   travel  02:00:00
Phoebe Buffey            2.0   travel  03:00:00
Ross Geller              2.0   travel  03:00:00
```

Note: Harry Kane partied from 7 am to 11 am so answer is 4 hours for him.

```
df.head()
              name  activity           timestamp  money_spent
0    Chandler Bing     party 2017-08-04 08:00:00           51
1    Chandler Bing     party 2017-08-04 13:00:00           60
2    Chandler Bing     party 2017-08-04 15:00:00           59
3       Harry Kane  football 2017-08-04 13:00:00           80
4       Harry Kane     party 2017-08-04 11:00:00           90
5       Harry Kane     party 2017-08-04 07:00:00           68
```

My attempt:

```
df.groupby(['name','activity'])['timestamp'].max() # no idea
```

Comment: Shouldn't `'Phoebe Buffey'` be 2 hours and `'Ross Geller'` be 2 hours on travel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below

```
s=df.groupby(['name','activity']).timestamp.apply(pd.Series.ptp).reset_index()
#s=df.groupby(['name','activity']).timestamp.apply(np.ptp).reset_index()
uni=s.groupby('name').activity.nunique()
s=s.sort_values('timestamp').drop_duplicates('name',keep='last')
s['numberofact']=s.name.map(uni)
s
             name activity timestamp  numberofact
4  Joey Tribbiani    party  01:00:00            2
6   Monica Geller   travel  02:00:00            1
8   Phoebe Buffey   travel  02:00:00            2
9     Ross Geller    party  02:00:00            2
2      Harry Kane    party  04:00:00            2
0   Chandler Bing    party  07:00:00            1
5        John Doe    beach  07:00:00            1
```

Comment: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
`

Comment: `TypeError: DatetimeIndex cannot perform the operation ptp`  after timestamp is made datetime dtype.

Comment: @astro123 did you run `df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
`

Comment: yes, if i run pd.to_datetime, then i got opertation ptp error.

Comment: @astro123 what is your pandas version ?

Comment: `pd.__version__  # '0.24.2'`

Comment: @astro123 did you import numpy ? like `import numpy as np`, ptp is numpy function

Comment: yes. `np.__version__  '1.16.2'` and help(np.ptp) works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191135/discussion-between-wen-ben-and-astro123).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
gb = df.groupby(['name', 'activity'])['timestamp']

print((gb.max() - gb.min()).sort_values(ascending=False).reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset='name'))
```

Output:

```
             name activity timestamp
0        John Doe    beach  07:00:00
1   Chandler Bing    party  07:00:00
2      Harry Kane    party  04:00:00
3     Ross Geller    party  02:00:00
4   Phoebe Buffey   travel  02:00:00
5   Monica Geller   travel  02:00:00
6  Joey Tribbiani    party  01:00:00
```

Comment: Agreed with @Wen-Ben Yeah, Phoebe played football from 12noon to 3pm, so time for her should be 3hrs not 2 hrs.

Comment: @Wen-Ben okay, I misunderstood the format of the input. Yes, this is not right.

Answer (score 1):

This is absolutely (probably) not the way to do it, but here we go:

```
### Get the max of the timestampe into separate dataframes
df_max = df.loc[df.groupby(['name','activity',])['timestamp'].idxmax()].reset_index(drop=True)
df_min = df.loc[df.groupby(['name','activity',])['timestamp'].idxmin()].reset_index(drop=True)

### Merge those puppies on the index values
df_tot = df_max.merge(df_min, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes= ('_max', '_min'))

### Subtract the max timestamp from the minimum timestamp
df_tot['net time'] = df_tot['timestamp_max'] - df_tot['timestamp_min']

### Drop unnecessary columns
df_tot.drop(['name_min','activity_min','timestamp_min','money_spent_min', 'money_spent_max','timestamp_max'], axis=1, inplace=True)

### Rename our columns
df_tot = df_tot.rename(columns={i:i.replace('_max', '') for i in df_tot.columns.values.tolist()})

### Set activity_number as the cumulative count of name
df_tot['activity_number'] = df_tot.groupby('name').cumcount() + 1

### Get the max of that result
df_tot = df_tot.loc[df_tot.groupby(['name',])['net time'].idxmax()].reset_index(drop=True)

### Rearrange our results
df_tot = df_tot.reindex(columns=['name','activity_number', 'net time']).copy()
```

Output:

```
             name  activity_number net time
0   Chandler Bing                1 07:00:00
1      Harry Kane                2 04:00:00
2  Joey Tribbiani                2 01:00:00
3        John Doe                1 07:00:00
4   Monica Geller                1 02:00:00
5   Phoebe Buffey                2 02:00:00
6     Ross Geller                1 02:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a discussion with @Wen-Ben and got the suggestions and got the answer.

```
# find maximum time spent for a given activity
df = pd.DataFrame([['Chandler Bing','party','2017-08-04 08:00:00',51],
 ['Chandler Bing','party','2017-08-04 13:00:00',60],
 ['Chandler Bing','party','2017-08-04 15:00:00',59],
 ['Harry Kane','football','2017-08-04 13:00:00',80],
 ['Harry Kane','party','2017-08-04 11:00:00',90],
 ['Harry Kane','party','2017-08-04 07:00:00',68],
 ['John Doe','beach','2017-08-04 07:00:00',63],
 ['John Doe','beach','2017-08-04 12:00:00',61],
 ['John Doe','beach','2017-08-04 14:00:00',65],
 ['Joey Tribbiani','party','2017-08-04 09:00:00',54],
 ['Joey Tribbiani','party','2017-08-04 10:00:00',67],
 ['Joey Tribbiani','football','2017-08-04 08:00:00',84],
 ['Monica Geller','travel','2017-08-04 07:00:00',90],
 ['Monica Geller','travel','2017-08-04 08:00:00',96],
 ['Monica Geller','travel','2017-08-04 09:00:00',74],
 ['Phoebe Buffey','travel','2017-08-04 10:00:00',52],
 ['Phoebe Buffey','travel','2017-08-04 12:00:00',84],
 ['Phoebe Buffey','football','2017-08-04 15:00:00',58],
 ['Ross Geller','party','2017-08-04 09:00:00',96],
 ['Ross Geller','party','2017-08-04 11:00:00',81],
 ['Ross Geller','travel','2017-08-04 14:00:00',60]],
 columns=['name','activity','timestamp','money_spent'])
```

The dataframe after sorting:

```
              name  activity           timestamp  money_spent
0    Chandler Bing     party 2017-08-04 08:00:00           51
1    Chandler Bing     party 2017-08-04 13:00:00           60
2    Chandler Bing     party 2017-08-04 15:00:00           59
5       Harry Kane     party 2017-08-04 07:00:00           68
4       Harry Kane     party 2017-08-04 11:00:00           90
3       Harry Kane  football 2017-08-04 13:00:00           80
11  Joey Tribbiani  football 2017-08-04 08:00:00           84
9   Joey Tribbiani     party 2017-08-04 09:00:00           54
10  Joey Tribbiani     party 2017-08-04 10:00:00           67
6         John Doe     beach 2017-08-04 07:00:00           63
7         John Doe     beach 2017-08-04 12:00:00           61
8         John Doe     beach 2017-08-04 14:00:00           65
12   Monica Geller    travel 2017-08-04 07:00:00           90
13   Monica Geller    travel 2017-08-04 08:00:00           96
14   Monica Geller    travel 2017-08-04 09:00:00           74
15   Phoebe Buffey    travel 2017-08-04 10:00:00           52
16   Phoebe Buffey    travel 2017-08-04 12:00:00           84
17   Phoebe Buffey  football 2017-08-04 15:00:00           58
18     Ross Geller     party 2017-08-04 09:00:00           96
19     Ross Geller     party 2017-08-04 11:00:00           81
20     Ross Geller    travel 2017-08-04 14:00:00           60
```

Answer:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df = df.sort_values(['name','timestamp'])

df['activity_change'] = (df.activity!=df.activity.shift()) | (df.name!=df.name.shift())
df['activity_num'] = df.groupby('name')['activity_change'].cumsum()

df['time_diff'] = df['timestamp'].diff()
df.loc[df.name != df.name.shift(), 'time_diff'] = None

activity_duration = df.groupby(['name','activity_num','activity'])['time_diff'].sum()
df1 = activity_duration.reset_index().groupby('name').max().drop('activity_num',1)
print(df1)
```

Gives:

```
               activity time_diff
name                             
Chandler Bing     party  07:00:00
Harry Kane        party  04:00:00
Joey Tribbiani    party  02:00:00
John Doe          beach  07:00:00
Monica Geller    travel  02:00:00
Phoebe Buffey    travel  03:00:00
Ross Geller      travel  03:00:00
```

Explanation:
For Phoebe, first activity is travel from 10am to 12noon is 2hrs. Second activity is 12noon to 3mp is 3hrs. football at 3pm does not have spent time so it is not taken into consideration.
So time for phoebe is 3hrs answer.